# Rainbow Brackets for the Mathematica GUI?

Tags: front-end, java

Is there a way to add rainbow bracket-pair colorization to the Mathematica / Wolfram Desktop GUI?

If not, how can I request one :)

This is one feature that I have grown to love when writing WL or lisp code, and I cannot stand trying to read any significant Mathematica expression without this nice visual indicator that easily tells you what level you are in at all times.

Examples of rainbow bracket plugins for other IDEs:

- [Sublime RainbowBrackets plugin](https://github.com/absop/RainbowBrackets)
- [VSCode Rainbow Brackets blog post](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/09/29/bracket-pair-colorization)
- [JetBrains RainbowBrackets plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets)

There are several vim and emacs plugins too; I think the movement started as an emacs plugin.

Comment: Dear WRI, if you actually do this, PLEASE make that optional. This MUST be turnoffable.

Comment: BTW, when you edit WL code in VSCode and use the Wolfram plug-in,  you get the rainbow brackets.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke just a remark, mathematica.stackexchange.com is not associated with Wolfram Research.

Comment: @yarchik correct.

Comment: This should be baked into the GUI and impossible to disable. Think of how many bugs would be prevented by structural highlighting; this change will make Mathematica as safe as Rust. /s